# ajax type post not working in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, laravel-5

Same function is working If I change type in Ajax as get and route as "    `Route::post('/delete','CandidateController@remove');`". In short get is working fine but post is not. I am getting this error in console

> VM2216:1 POST http://localhost/nor_management/public/delete 419
>   (unknown status) (anonymous) @ VM2216:1 send @ app.js:29 ajax @
>   app.js:29 (anonymous) @ home:110 dispatch @ app.js:29 g.handle @
>   app.js:29 VM2216:1 XHR failed loading: POST
>   "http://localhost/nor_management/public/delete".

Ajax call:

```
 $(document).on('click','#delete',function(){
                    var dataId = $(this).data("id");

                    $.ajax({

                        type:'POST',
                        url:"{!! URL::to('delete') !!}",
                        data:{'id':dataId,},
                        dataType: 'JSON',


                        success:function(data){
                            console.log('success');
                            console.log(data);
                            console.log(data.length);
                           $("#table").load("data");
                        },
                        error:function(){

                        },
                    });
                });
            });
```

Form:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12"  >
            <div class="panel panel-default" >
                <div class="panel-heading"><a href="add">Add New Candidate</a></div>

                <div class="panel-body">
                        <meta type="hidden" name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
                    <div class="table-responsive" >

                        @include('data')
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Routes:

```
Route::post('/delete','CandidateController@remove');
```

Controller:

```
public function remove(Request $request){
        $id  = $request->id;
        $candidate = new Candidate;
        $candidate->where('id', '=', $id)->delete();
    }
```

Comment: I'd be looking in the server-side error log

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).on('click','#delete',function(){
    var dataId = $(this).data("id");
    var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
    $.ajax({

        type:'POST',
        url:"{!! URL::to('delete') !!}",
        dataType: 'JSON',
        data: {
            "_method": 'POST',
            "_token": token,
            "id": dataId,
        },
        success:function(data){
            console.log('success');
            console.log(data);
            console.log(data.length);
           $("#table").load("data");
        },
        error:function(){

        },
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked :), what I have found is that you have to send token and method inside data as well